# How to connect to my Cloud SQL instance At the Cloud Shell prompt?

Tags: android, sql-server, shell, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

i am trying to connect my Cloud sql with cloud shell but i got error.
"ERROR: (gcloud.beta.sql.connect) HTTPError 403: The client is not authorized to make this request."
i use comment sfs_arunkumar17@zinc-presence-165610:~$ gcloud beta sql connect myinstance --user=arunsharma.

please share your answer.

Comment: gcloud beta sql connect mydatabasename --user=root   this command i use for connect with sql but i am getting problem now in next step in appenzine how to check my app is run and in web view